# Create EventGrid subscription with az cli

Tags: powershell, azure-cli, azure-eventgrid

I'm creating an event subscription with this command:

```sh
az eventgrid event-subscription create --source-resource-id "/subscriptions/mysubscription/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/mytopic" --name "new-subscription" --endpoint-type "webhook" --endpoint "https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName=myfunction&code=mymasterkey"
```

But allways, i receive this error message:

```
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 154239e9-9992-4c4c-a991-83b88cc9bd91. Webhook validation handshake failed for https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid. Http POST request failed with response code Unknown. For troublehooting, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation. Activity id:a9a4804c-927f-4bc4-8f0b-99d80eed08a3, timestamp: 7/14/2020 10:20:28 AM (UTC).
```

What's wrong?

Comment: It seems the key is not validating. What does the ARM template look like? What API are you using?

Comment: can you try using *Cloud Shell* on your portal? also use the url from the *Get function URL* on the portal. I just created one and it is straightforward.

Comment: @Gerhard I just check az version on azure cloud shell and local, and version is 2.8.0 in both of them

Comment: @RomanKiss on Cloud Shell the command works fine, but not on my local

Comment: I've notice what @RomanKiss has pointed out as well, some Azure CLI commands do not work as expected locally but execute flawlessly in the Cloud Shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error, it seems that your function URL is not right and it cannot finish validation. The function URL should be like `https://{functionappname}.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/eventgrid?functionName={functionname}&code={systemkey}`. You can get it via Azure Portal. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=csharp)

For example

```
az eventgrid event-subscription create  -n "test" --source-resource-id "<my topic resource id>"  --endpoint "https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName=myfunction&code=mymasterkey"
```

[image]

Besides, since you use Azure function event ride trigger, you can directly use the function app resource id as the endpoint. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/eventgrid/eventgrid/event-subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-eventgrid-az-eventgrid-event-subscription-create) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/issues/1713)

For example

```
az extension add --name eventgrid

az eventgrid event-subscription create --name "test1" \
    --source-resource-id /subscriptions/{SubID}/resourceGroups/{RG}/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/topic1 \
    --endpoint /subscriptions/{SubID}/resourceGroups/{RG}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{functionappname}/functions/{functionname} \
   --endpoint-type azurefunction
```

[image]
[image]